# how to use actionscript components code in mmxl components

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

how i can use actionscript component code in mmxl components,as in actionscript  components we  use classes ,but in  mmxl component we can not use classes function, so how i can use actionscript component code in mmxl component

example,,

this is actionscript component code

```
package components
{
    import assets.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import mx.binding.*;
    import mx.containers.*;
    import mx.controls.*;
    import mx.core.*;
    import mx.events.*;
    import mx.styles.*;

    public class DialogTitle extends HBox implements IBindingClient
    {
        private var title:String = "TitleDialog";
        public var DialogTitle1Image1:Image;
        public var DialogTitle2Image2:Image;
        public var DialogTitle3Label1:Label;
        var _bindingsBeginWithWord:Object;
        private var showCloseButton:Boolean = false;
        var _bindingsByDestination:Object;
        var _watchers:Array;
        var _bindings:Array;
        private var _documentDescriptor_:UIComponentDescriptor;
        private static var _watcherSetupUtil:IWatcherSetupUtil;
```

but i cant use this code in mmxl components how i can use public class DialogTitle extends HBox implements IBindingClient  in mmxl component code,what are the way to use it,sorry i am newbie if it is silly question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can derive class from HBox and make it implement interface:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox
    implements="com.interfaces.IBindingClient"
>
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
     //and code goes here
]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:HBox>
```

Note that interface must be specified with full path, imports have no effect on it.

Comment: IBindingClient is in mx.binding but in autoshow function IBindingClient not showing is it problem of sdk

Comment: do you have any idea in which sdk it work? or any web resource from which i can find

Comment: I can see it in Flex 4 project, so it must be Spark specific.